# Facebook SDK for Android "An error has occurred with MyApp. Please try again later"

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I get this error all the time now for some reason when everything was working fine and posting to my wall just days before.

My expiration token I believe is set to unlimited so I am out of ideas why it would just randomly stop working.

Does anyone else have/had this ? What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using the `dialog` method to post to the wall, or are you doing it yourself? If you are using the `dialog` method, do you get any callbacks on the `DialogListener`? `onFacebookError` or `onError` should give you more information about the error.

Comment: Yeah useing the dialog method - I have all of those error functions but none of them are triggered

Answer (score 1):

```
110 error_code = Missing User Cookie (as in Jamie's comment)
```

For me, this came up in my App when I logged out of the '`Facebook`' App that cleared the cookie (after prompting for confirmation). Now, coming back to my App, the facebook object still holds the stale '`access_token`' and the previous session data.

I got around this, by trapping '`110`' error after '`post_id`' is returned as '`null`'. If found, do a '`logout`()' and then ask for a re-login to get hold of a new '`access_token`' before posting new messages.

Answer (score 0):

have at look at the following links:

http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

the above should help you to debug any errors. My error was more to do with the build path of some of the classes that where in my project, mainly the "main" XML file that android reads from.

Comment: Yes, using the LogCat, I found - "DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(15156): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success/?error_code=110&error_msg=Missing+user+cookie+%28to+validate­+session+user%29" - Any ideas how to fix that ?