# Facebook iOS SDK user cookie issue in FBWebdialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbwebdialogs

I am getting awkward issue in iOS app when I try to post on friend's wall using `FBWebDialog`

```
fbconnect://success?error_code=110&error_msg=Missing+user+cookie+%28to+validate+session+user%29
```

In which I am using stored access_token on server and creating session using that on every device when user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot be sure, the issue seems to be with the access token that you are using. You mentioned 'stored' access token so it is possible that the access token had already expired when you made the request. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5780219/405525) may point you in the right direction.